# How to repeatedly attach object A for every object B in python?

Tags: python

```
raw_data_row = { "account_level_data" : {"account_name": "A", "currency" :"USD"} "store_level_data" : {"store_name": "MySotre", "address" :"MyStreet"}, item_values : [{"name": "a", "price" : 30}, {"name": "b", "price" : 40}]}
```

How can I create an object like that:

```
new data = 
[{ "account_name": "A", "currency" :"USD", "store_name":"MySotre", "address":"MyStreet", "name": "a", "price" : 30}
{ "account_name": "A", "currency" :"USD", "store_name":"MySotre", "address":"MyStreet", "name": "b", "price" : 40}]
```

Right now I specify every attribute name and values manually, any way to do it more generic?

```
new_rows = []
for item in raw_data_row.item_values:
    new_rows.add({"account_name" :raw_data_row.account_level_data.account_name, "currency" :raw_data_row.account_level_data.currency, "store_name" :raw_data_row.store_level_data.store_name, "address" :raw_data_row.store_level_data.address, "name" : item.name, "price":item.price})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, if the data are dictionaries, in Python 3.9:

```
raw_data_row = {"account_level_data": {"account_name": "A", "currency": "USD"},
                "store_level_data": {"store_name": "MySotre", "address": "MyStreet"},
                "item_values": [{"name": "a", "price": 30}, {"name": "b", "price": 40}]}

account_data = raw_data_row["account_level_data"]
store_data = raw_data_row["store_level_data"]
res = [value | account_data | store_data for value in raw_data_row["item_values"]]

for row in res:
    print(row)
```

**Output**

```
{'name': 'a', 'price': 30, 'account_name': 'A', 'currency': 'USD', 'store_name': 'MySotre', 'address': 'MyStreet'}
{'name': 'b', 'price': 40, 'account_name': 'A', 'currency': 'USD', 'store_name': 'MySotre', 'address': 'MyStreet'}
```

For previous Python versions, and a lot whole more see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression).

Comment: Do you know if this can also be done for js easily?

Comment: By js you mean Javascript?

Comment: Yes, found it: `let food = {...a,...b}`